# Writing an cross-platform app that has messaging between devices?

Tags: android, ios, api, xmpp, messaging

I am trying to write an app that has a messaging feature in it. It needs to have the ability to handle pictures and other types of generic data files. It also should be push and almost instant. Also, it would be great if there was a way for it to be cross-platform, especially between iOS and Android. I am not very familiar with any of the current protocols for handling push messaging. One idea I had was XMPP, but I don't think that is how very many apps do it. What protocols are used by apps like Facebook Messenger? I know that some sort of REST HTTP framework could be used, is that the best way?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: You should look at parse.com. They do pretty much what you're looking for iirc

Comment: It seems really powerful, but I don't quite see how it can be used for user to user messaging, am I missing something?

Comment: To my knowledge, XMPP is used in many applications in GGPlay. Wechat, GOSMS, Whatsapp,Cubie,LINE,Gtalk is also use XMPP.

Comment: @Yul do you know what API those apps use?

Comment: GTalk use its own implementation based on XMPP. Others use Smack. For Android you can search for A-Smack. For iOS use `xmppframework` library. If you're interested in XMPP, i'll add an answer with resource link.

Comment: If those XMPP APIs can handle file transfers, I'm definitely interested!

Comment: With file transfer, it's a little bit headache :). I had problem with it before and change to upload to my server not using XMPP. But i just found some patch indicate that it fix the problem. I haven't got time to check that. My problem is it can't receive file on real device. Emulator and PC worked fine.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To my knowledge, XMPP is used in many applications in GGPlay such as Wechat, GOSMS, Whatsapp,Cubie,LINE,Gtalk... is also use XMPP. GTalk use its own implementation based on XMPP. Others use Smack. For Android you can use [A-Smack](http://code.google.com/p/asmack/) which not supported longtime ago. Another option is [Beem](http://beem-project.com/) which is current develop and improved. For iOS use [xmppframework](https://github.com/robbiehanson/XMPPFramework) library. You can find libraries for others languages [here](http://xmpp.org/xmpp-software/libraries/)